# MongoDB how using Spring Cryteria remove element from nested object array

Tags: spring, mongodb

In my project I'm using SpringBoot 1.3.2 and org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.*

I'm trying to remove element from nested object array, in my main object i have array looking like this:

```
"sections" : [
        {
                "sectionId" : "56cc3c908f5e6c56e677bd2e",
                "name" : "Wellcome"
        },
        {
                "sectionId" : "56cc3cd28f5e6c56e677bd2f",
                "name" : "Hello my friends"
        }
]
```

Using Spring I want to delete record with sectionId 56cc3c908f5e6c56e677bd2e

This is way I'm trying do this:

```
  Query query = Query.query(Criteria
                .where("sections")
                .elemMatch(
                        Criteria.where("sectionId").is("56cc3c908f5e6c56e677bd2e")
                )
        );
        Update update = new Update().unset("sections.sectionId");
        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Offer.class);
```

Query is finding propper element but there is something wrong with Update and I don't know what so removing is not working.

Could any body can help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I need the practice anyway, here's a *guess* to as what you want.

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria
                .where("sections")
                .elemMatch(
                        Criteria.where("sectionId").is("56cc3c908f5e6c56e677bd2e")
                )
        );

Update update = 
   new Update().pull("sections", 
       new BasicDBObject("sectionId", "56cc3c908f5e6c56e677bd2e"));

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Offer.class);
```

resulting in

```
"sections" : [
    {
        "sectionId" : "56cc3cd28f5e6c56e677bd2f",
        "name" : "Hello my friends"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Man that works fine for me, but how it is that pull is working like remove, it's like pulling from stack i suppose but there is no logic in this :D

Comment: @zaqpiotr I must admit the naming is odd, although there is a `$push` operator to add something at the end of an array that may make more sense since the operation is similar to a stack operation, and `$pull` may only be a somewhat misguided attempt to use consistent naming.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for query

```
Update update = 
   new Update().pull("sections", 
       new BasicDBObject("sectionId", "56cc3c908f5e6c56e677bd2e"));

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(), update, Offer.class);
```

That solution is perfectly working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the accepted answer necessarily works for all cases with BAsicDbObject class. Springboot would need the the class of the object you are trying to pull/delet in order for it to properly map it, so here is how I did it:

```
var sectionToRemove = new Section()
        . sectionId("56cc3c908f5e6c56e677bd2e");

var updateAction = new Update().pull("sections", sectionToRemove);

var res = mongoOps.updateMulti(query, updateAction, Section.class);
```